# Secure web programming - Best practises in authenticating users

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, https

Getting into web development and would like to become good at making secure websites.  Any general typs/answers to any of the below would be greatly appreciated.

So got some questions on the authentication side of things:

1. How should the password  typed on the client be encoded and sent to the server - assuming https is already in use?  i have heard of some suggesting that only the hash is sent for security for example.  Should it be encrypted client side - how?
2. 1. Similar but on server side.  How should the passwords be saved.  Actual, hash, etc?  Should they be encrypted - how? 
      Also, is there a kind of architecture that can protect the passwords in such a way that if one password is compromised, not everyone else's is?  For example, if all passwords are stored in one file then access to only this one file  would compromise every user on the system.
   2. if only hashes must be stored - how to handle collisions?
3. Once authenticated should you just rely on session IDs to maintain authenticated status throughout?  I have read on tips to reduce session highjacking and was therefore wondering whether it is a good idea/the only idea in the first place for keeping users authenticated.
4. Is there a safe way to provide an autoLogIn feature so that the browser remembers the password - similar to social network/web-email clients?
  -------------
  Extra - preventing attacks
5. 1. Are there any tools or even just some common practises  out there that must be applied to the username/password entries provided to prevent injection or any other kind of attacks?
   2. If I use a Java development environment (using PlayFrameWork btw) how likely is it in general that attackers could include harmful code snippets of any kind in any form entries?

PS
As mentioned I will probably be using the Java PlayFrameWork to encode the website - can you suggest anything I should take into account for this?
Any tips  on design patterns that must be followed for security purposes would be helpful.

Many Thanks
PPS
You could suggest passing the job on to an expert but if possible I would like to have some experience coding it myself.  I hope that this is a viable option?
Will probably like to set up an e-commerce  system FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should the password typed on the client be encoded and sent to the server - assuming https is already in use? i have heard of some suggesting that only the hash is sent for security for example. Should it be encrypted client side - how?

It should not be sent to the server in a way that can be recovered. The problem with SSL/TLS and PKI is the {username, password} (or {username, hash(password)}) is presented to nearly any server that answers with a certificate. That server could be good or bad.

The problem here is channel setup is disjoint from user authentication, and web developers and server administrators then do dumb things like put a plain text password on the wire in a `basic_auth` scheme.

Its better to integrate SSL/TLS channel setup with authentication. That's called channel binding. Its provides mutual authentication and does not do dumb things like put a {username, password} on the wire so it can be easily recovered.

SSL/TLS offers nearly 80 cipher suites that don't do the dumb {username, password} on the wire. They are Preshared Key (PSK) and Secure Remote Password (SRP). Even if a bad guy answers (i.e., controls the server), the attacker cannot learn the password because its not put on the wire for recovery. Instead, he will have to break AES (for PSK) or solve the Discrete Log problem (for SRP).

All of this is covered in great detail in Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf) book.

> Similar but on server side. How should the passwords be saved. Actual, hash, etc? Should they be encrypted - how?

See the [Secure Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and [Secure Password Storage paper](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g/) John Steven wrote for OWASP. It takes you through the entire threat model, and explains why things are done in particular ways.

> Once authenticated should you just rely on session IDs to maintain authenticated status throughout?

Yes, but authorization is different than authentication.

Authentication is a "coarse grained" entitlement. It asks the question, "can a user use this application?". Authorization is a "fine grained" entitlement. It answers the question, "can a user access this resource?".

> Is there a safe way to provide an autoLogIn feature so that the browser remembers the password - similar to social network/web-email clients

It depends on what you consider safe and what's in the threat model. If your threat model does not include an attacker who has physical access to a user's computer or device, then its probably "safe" by most standards.

If the attacker has access to a computer or device, and the user does not protect it with a password or pin, then its probably not considered "safe".

> Are there any tools or even just some common practises out there that must be applied to the username/password entries provided to prevent injection or any other kind of attacks?

Yes, user login suffers injections. So you can perform some filtering on the way in, but you must perform HTML encoding on the output.

Its not just username/password and logins. Nearly everything should have some input filtering; and it must have output encoding in case its malicious.

You should definitely spend so time on the [OWASP web site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page). If you have a local chapter, you might even consider attending meetings. You will learn a lot, and meet a lot of awesome people.

> If I use a Java development environment (using PlayFrameWork btw) how likely is it in general that attackers could include harmful code snippets of any kind in any form entries?

Java is a hacker's delight. Quality and security has really dropped since Oracle bought it from Sun. The more paranoid (security conscious?) folks recommend *not* signing any Java code because the sandbox is so broken. That keeps a legitimate application properly sandboxed. From http://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy:

> ...
>   “The sandbox is a huge problem for Oracle,” Jongerius told Threatpost.
>   “Everyone is breaking in. Their solution is to code-sign and get out
>   of the sandbox. But then, you have full permission to the machine. It
>   doesn’t make sense.”

Its too bad the bad guys didn't get the memo. They sign their code the malware and break out of the sandbox.

> Any tips on design patterns that must be followed for security purposes would be helpful.

You also have web server configurations, like `HTTPS Only` and `Secure` cookies, HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), and Content Security Policies (CSP), Suhosin (hardened PHP), SSL/TLS algorithms, and the like.

There's a lot to it, and you will need to find the appropriate hardening guide.

Comment: Hey thank you so much - that's really informative.  Two questions - Could you explain or link to a little more about channel binding?  What is it  exactly? Second - say you want to send some confidential information - (credit card number, whatever) is it safe enough to rely on https to encrypt it or should another encryption be applied?  Would a PKI method work with this then?

Comment: "say you want to send some confidential information - (credit card number, whatever)..." A credit card number is sensitive information just like a password, and it will be exposed to the same risks. The difference is: your organization suffers when the single sign-on password is lost; while the bank suffers when the credit card number is lost. So the risk on a credit card is almost non-existent from your point of view because an external entity suffers it (modulo losing the card number to make automatic and one-click payments).

Comment: "... a little more about channel binding" - channel binding is a concept where secure channel setup and user authentication are combined into a single logical operation. Currently, the most frequently used systems are disjoint - secure channel setup occurs at the socket layer; while user authentication occurs at the application layer. In practice, we know bad guys take advantage of the security engineering defect. Nico Williams is working for a generic specification for IETF standardization: [On the Use of Channel Bindings to Secure Channels](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc5056).